# How to Convert List in to Sql Query format in Python?

Tags: python

I need to covert my dictionary to a sql query, but it is not coming in a way I wanted.

Example:

```
table_name_info = {'table1': 'Product', 'table2': 'Sales'}
table_columns_info={'Product': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Sales': ['*']}
```

I tried:

```
sql_query=[]
for i in table_name_info:
    table_name=table_name_info[i]
    col_details= table_columns_info[table_name]
    sql_query.append("SELECT %s FROM %s " %(col_details,table_name))
    return None
```

My_Output:

```
print(sql_query)
["SELECT ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] FROM Products",
 "SELECT ['*'] FROM Sales"]
```

Expected_Output:

```
["Products_Table_Query": "SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Products",
     "Sales_Table_Query":"SELECT * FROM Sales"]
```

Comment: you can use ", ".join(col_details) for your matter.

In addition, this seems very prone to SQL injection, please make sure to prevent it, and don't use user-inputted data directly to create that query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can use join method of list to get the columns of tables.
2. there is no need to return
3. sql_query is a dict not a list according your program output.

```
table_name_info = {'table1': 'Product', 'table2': 'Sales'}
table_columns_info={'Product': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Sales': ['*']}

sql_query={}
for i in table_name_info:
    table_name=table_name_info[i]
    col_details= table_columns_info[table_name]
    sql_query[f"{table_name}_Table_Query"] = f"SELECT {', '.join(col_details)} FROM {table_name}"
print(sql_query)
```

output

```
{'Product_Table_Query': 'SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Product', 'Sales_Table_Query': 'SELECT * FROM Sales'}
```

Comment: by the way, in your case, you do not need table_name_info

Answer (score 0):

you need to join list

```
table_name_info = {"table1": "Product", "table2": "Sales"}
table_columns_info = {"Product": ["A", "B", "C", "D"], "Sales": ["*"]}

sql_query = []
for i in table_name_info:
    table_name = table_name_info[i]
    col_details = table_columns_info[table_name]
    sql_query.append("SELECT %s FROM %s " % (", ".join(col_details), table_name))

print(sql_query[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same thing as the other answers but written in a more pythonic way.
I know that for some people, it's more natural to see it written like that:

```py
table_name_info = {'table1': 'Product', 'table2': 'Sales'}
table_columns_info={'Product': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Sales': ['*']}

sql_query = {f"{table_name}_Table_Query": "SELECT {0} FROM {1}".format(", ".join(table_columns_info[table_name]), table_name) for table_name in table_name_info.values()}
```

Comment: When mentioning "most pythonic way", please make sure your code adheres to at least python code style (PEP8). Current code would never pass human reviewer due to giant line length.